# C# Drag & Drop Between ListViews

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I'm trying to create a self-contained Winforms control called DragDropListView. It derives from ListView.

I have code that allows the user to sort list items within the control by dragging and dropping the items in the new location. I achieved that by overriding OnDragDrop, OnDragOver, OnDragEnter, OnItemDrag.

The issue I have is with dragging from one listview to a completely different listview. The event fires on the other list view as expected, but the method doesn't take a "sender" argument, so there's no good way to tell where the items are being dragged from, and no way I can figure out to actually grab the items being dragged. The current code works with stuff like "this.SelectedItems," but I'd like it to be "sender.SelectedItems".

I guess the reason there is no sender argument is that the control isn't supposed to responsible for knowing that much about its environment, and the host Form should handle the interaction between two controls, but I'm trying to build self contained controls that have this functionality, so letting it bleed onto the form isn't going to work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can know the `ListView` from the Items by `listViewItem.ListView` property, Check it.

I didn't test the code:

```
private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(ListView.ListViewItemCollection)))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        return;
    }

    var items = (ListView.ListViewItemCollection)e.Data.GetData(typeof(ListView.ListViewItemCollection));

    if (items.Count > 0 && items[0].ListView != listView1)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        return;
    }
}
```

Check [DragEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.drageventargs.aspx) , this sample in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/gListViewControl.aspx) [VB.Net]
Good luck!

Comment: It's a good thought, but remember I don't necessarily have the item being dragged if it's being dragged from a different ListView-- I can only access the item through this.SelectedItems, and if "this" isn't the source of the item, then I don't think I can get the item. Make sense?

Comment: No, you can, you can get it by DragEventArgs, I'll edit my answer and add the code.